# There is no Alexa Smart Home trigger

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-smart-home-skill

I'm following the [official documentation](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/smarthome/steps-to-build-a-smart-home-skill.html) while creating the Alexa Smart Home skill. The Create a Lambda function and add code step, point 6 is asking me to "…select the Alexa Smart Home trigger". But there is no Alexa Smart home trigger in the Triggers list. Do I do something wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I just noticed this too, but quickly realized that it is not on the Ohio server.  You must choose N. Virginia, EU (Ireland), or US West (Oregon).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've found the problem. The Alexa Smart Home trigger is not available in the EU server location!

Comment: The `Alexa Smart Home` trigger is available in Ireland for English (UK), English (IN), German or French (FR) skills

Comment: I don't believe this is the correct solution.  I am using the US server location and I am not able to select the Alexa Smart Home trigger

Answer (score 0):

I was struck on this for a while until I did realise, that smart home is available at very limited place. For example they've mentioned in the I formation section as well to select the smart home. For India, Europe. They've suggested to select Ireland. This is explicitly available in Lambda function as Smart Home Skill.